# Instantiate prefab inside canvas

Tags: c#, canvas, unity-game-engine

I need to instantiate a prefab inside canvas, already tried several solutions but none worked. Can you help?

This is my script:

```
    class Smoke1 : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject myPrefab;
        public GameObject canvasObject;

        void Start()
        {
           Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, -25, 90), Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0));
           myPrefab.transform.SetParent(canvasObject.transform, false);
           myPrefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried with this:

```
myPrefab.transform.parent = canvasObject.transform;
```

But did not worked either. The prefab instance initiates outside canvas.
This is my hierarchy:
[image] 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: but it did not work.....That's your only problem?

Comment: The problem is that the prefab is not instantiated inside canvas.

Comment: That is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Then you should put this problem to your question. Also put a screenshot of what you meant by not instantiated inside canvas.

Comment: Did you check in hierarchy that the prefab instance is not under canvas ? Or are you just saying that it is not appearing in canvas in game view. In this case you need to re-position it after setting parent.

Comment: @UmairM That's the problem. Question is not even and clear and requires at-least 4 comments to explain the actual problem.

Comment: @Programmer I am sorry, you are right. I edited the question to better explain it. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code instead.

I had tried your code and it threw me this error message:

> Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a prefab is disabled to prevent data corruption.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Smoke1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject myPrefab;
    public GameObject canvasObject;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject newSmoke = Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, -25, 90), Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
        newSmoke.transform.SetParent(canvasObject.transform, false);
        newSmoke.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Your main problem was that you were trying to setParent of myPrefab which isn't the instance you created.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.